# Уточняющий оборот 3

Tags: запятые, уточнения

Вопрос следующий. В нижеследующем предложении нужно выделять дату запятыми?.. Это уточнение?.. А можно ли не обособлять?..

Вот и оказалось, что в решающий день 27 июля 1976 года мне выпала ночная смена.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обособление факультативно. Если автор действительно воспринимает эту дату как уточнение при "решающем дне", то обособление оправдано. Иначе это единая конструкция (день - какой? - 27 июня) и обосоления не требуется.
Я бы скорее не обособлял. В подобном сочетании ("решаюший день"+дата) да еще в стилистически явно художественом тексте вариант с обособлением смотрится несколько странно.

Comment: Спасибо. Разрешили мои сомнения.